# how to calculate float number using precision in python

Tags: python

```
precision = 2
number = 31684.28
result = Decimal(number) - Decimal(10 ** -precision)
print(result)
```

Desired output:

```
31684.27
```

Actual output:

```
31684.26999999999883584657356
```

What I try to do is to subtract `0.01` from `number`.

Comment: First of all, why do you subtract precision from number? o_O

Comment: I just want to subtract 0.01

Answer (score 3):

You should use formating like the following:

```
print("{:.2f}".format(result))
```

Or using `round` like:

```
print(round(result, 2))
```

### comment

The question wasn't clear from the start. The correct answer (in my opinion is of @U11-Forward)

Comment: He already using `Decimal` which should solve this problem. Issue is in `10 ** -price_precision`.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants tho... anyway he isn't clear on this

Comment: @U11-Forward yes, he just now commented that he wanted to subtract 0.01. Wasnt clear from the start. You picked it up nicely!

Comment: @DavidS Yeah I think maybe now my answer is more *possible* to work for him

Answer (score 3):

You have to make the values with `Decimal(...)` not the output. So try this:

```
from decimal import Decimal
precision = 2
number = 31684.28
result = number - float(10 ** Decimal(-precision))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
31684.27
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `round`
The syntax is: `round(number, digits)`
So, `result = round(number, 2)`

You can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `quantize` method of decimal [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal)

```
from decimal import Decimal


result = Decimal('31684.26999999999883584657356').quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
# result = Decimal('31684.27')
```